# How do you get aws-sdk version in node.js?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I know you are supposed to call getVersion() of the VersionInfoUtils class to get the aws-sdk version, but how exactly does that look like in node.js code?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/VersionInfoUtils.html

Comment: You mention NodeJS in your question, but you linked to the Java AWS SDK. http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 1):

`var AWS = require("aws-sdk"); console.log('-- aws-sdk version--', AWS.VERSION);`